# Javascript - the day of the week index is wrong on October 31

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the processing of dates in javascript, I tested this script to have the index of the first day of the first week of the month of November 2023.
The expected result is 2 (Wednesday)

```
const d = new Date();
d.setMonth(10); // november index
d.setFullYear(2023); 
d.setDate(0); 
let day = d.getDay();
console.log('day',day);
```

This is correct
but when I initialize my date to October 31, 2023 using this script :

```
const d = new Date(2023,9,31);
d.setMonth(10);
d.setFullYear(2023);
d.setDate(0);
let day = d.getDay();
console.log(day);
```

I get the wrong result -> 4 (Friday)

Does anyone have an explanation?

```
const d = new Date(2023,9,31);
d.setMonth(10);
d.setFullYear(2023);
d.setDate(0);
let day = d.getDay();
console.log(day);
```

the expected result is 2

Comment: the date is 1-indexed. What do you expect with `setDate(0)`?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina As stated on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate): *"while a dateValue of 0 changes the date to the last day of the previous month"*

Comment: `new Date(2023,9,31)` is the 31st of October. `d.setMonth(10)` (November) doesn't have 31 days. What do you expect `d.setMonth(10)` to do in this case?

Comment: @ivar I want to simulate the behavior as of October 31 because this bug only happens on October 31

Comment: I don't think you really understand my comment. The bug happens for any date where you start at the 31st of any month and use `.setMonth()` to a month that doesn't have 31 days. Have a look what the actual value of `d` is at every step: https://jsfiddle.net/7ewLo0r3/ After `d.setMonth(10)`, the value of `d` isn't the 31st of November (the 31st of november _doesn't exist_), but December 1st.

Comment: @Ivar : Maybe I explained my problem badly, I have a bug in my homemade DatePicker, the bug only occurs on October 31st. here is my actual code, when it is executed on October 31 the value returned by startDay is wrong. I purposely put the date 31 in new Date() to simulate.. 

    `var d = new Date() ;
      d.setMonth(m);
      d.setFullYear(y) ;
      d.setDate(0) ;
    var startDay = d.getDay();
    var maxDays = daysInMonth(m,y) ;`

her m and y are the month and year selected in my DatePicker

Comment: @Ivar `var d = new Date() ;       d.setMonth(m);//m is the selected month in my DatePicker (10 for november)       d.setFullYear(y)  //y is the selected year on my DP;       d.setDate(0) ;     var startDay = d.getDay();     var maxDays = daysInMonth(m,y) ; `

I want the start day to be able to set it to the day of the week exp: first of November 2023 is a Wednesday whereas with my code it sets to Friday (only October 31)

Comment: If you want to get the day of the week of the first month, then first set the `date` to `1`, and _then_ set the month and year. See https://jsfiddle.net/p4o68adj/ Note that you mention that `4` is Friday, but that's not true. **4 is a Thursday**. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: You:  `const d = new Date(2023,9,31); d.setMonth(10);`  Everybody:  "That's actually December 1st because there are 30 days in November".  You: no that's **NOVEMBER 31st**.  Everyone:  ?!?  You: `d.setDate(0)` (last day of previous month).  Everybody:  That's now November 30th.  You:  Happy Halloween!

Comment: @Ivar : the expected index : 0 -> Monday, 1 -> Tuesday , 2 -> Wednesday ...etc 
In my DatePicker , first november 2023 appears on friday and i expect Wednesday , your code is wrong too ..

Comment: But as the link I provided in my last comment explains, that is not what `d.getDay()` returns. I think this is the source of your problems. `getDay()` returns `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet,the month 9 is over-rided by month 10 which under the hood looks like new Date(2023, 10, 31) and there is no 31 november due to which the month turns 11 and date is set to 1 dec 2023. This is happening because you have initialized the date constructor initially due to which the output is 4. the flow is like this:

```
const d = new Date(2023, 9, 31);
console.log('m', d.getMonth());
d.setMonth(10);
console.log(d.getMonth());
// output: 11
d.setFullYear(2023);
d.setDate(0);
console.log(d.getDate(), d.getMonth())
// output: 30 10
let day = d.getDay();
console.log('day', day);
//ouput: day 4
```

now to get the expected output set the const d = new Date(2023, 9, 30);
you'll get output as 2;

P.S: If you have any doubt feel free to ask :)